# The Rust Programming Language book: Company HashMap exercise (Ch. 8)

Tags: hash-map, rust

This is my solution to the third exercise (and last) at the end of chapter 8 of The Rust Programming Language book (https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch08-03-hash-maps.html#summary).

There are only 3 types of commands: ADD, GET and EXIT:

- **ADD** syntax: ADD name TO department (where "name" and "department" are variables)
- **GET** syntax: GET department (we can also use ALL instead of department variable to get the employees of all the departments)
- **EXIT**: exit the program

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::io;

// get the employees from all departments
fn get_all_employees(dict: &HashMap<String, Vec<String>>) -> Vec<String> {
    let mut employees = Vec::new();
    for (_, v) in dict.iter() {
        for employee in v {
            employees.push(employee.to_string());
        }
    }   
    employees
}

// get the employees from a department 
fn get_dept_employees(dept: &str, dict: &HashMap<String, Vec<String>>) -> Vec<String> {
    let employees = dict.get(dept);
    match employees {
        Some(v) => v.to_vec(),
        None => {
            println!("No such department.");
            vec![]
        },
    }
}

// execute an ADD command 
fn exec_add(cmd_tokens: &Vec<&str>, dict: &mut HashMap<String, Vec<String>>) {

    if cmd_tokens.len() != 4 {
        println!("Invalid command.");
        return;
    }

    // add employee name to department (create it if non-existent)
    let dept = dict.entry(cmd_tokens[3].to_string()).or_insert(Vec::new());
    dept.push(cmd_tokens[1].to_string());
    println!("'{}' added to '{}' department.", cmd_tokens[1], cmd_tokens[3]);
}

// execute a GET command
fn exec_get(cmd_tokens: &Vec<&str>, dict: &mut HashMap<String, Vec<String>>) {

    if cmd_tokens.len() != 2 {
        println!("Invalid command.");
        return;
    }

    let mut employees: Vec<String> = Vec::new();

    match cmd_tokens.get(1) {
        Some(&"ALL") => employees = get_all_employees(&dict),
        Some(dept) => employees = get_dept_employees(dept, &dict),
        _ => println!("Invalid command."),
    }

    employees.sort();
    for employee in employees {
        println!("{}", employee);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut dict: HashMap<String, Vec<String>> = HashMap::new();
    loop {

        // read command from stdin 
        let mut cmd = String::new();
        println!("Enter database command: ");
        io::stdin()
            .read_line(&mut cmd)
            .expect("Failed to read from stdin");
        cmd = cmd.trim().to_string();
        
        // parse command and execute
        let tokens: Vec<&str> = cmd.split_whitespace().collect();
        if let Some(action) = tokens.get(0) {
            match action {
                &"ADD" => exec_add(&tokens, &mut dict),
                &"GET" => exec_get(&tokens, &mut dict),
                &"EXIT" => break,
                _ => println!("Invalid command."),
            }
        };
    }
    println!("Bye.");
}
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The `get_all_employees` function can be simplified using iterators

```rust
fn get_all_employees(dict: &HashMap<String, Vec<String>>) -> Vec<String> {
  dict
    .values()
    .map(|v| v.iter())
    .flatten()
    .map(Clone::clone)
    .collect()
}
```

Similarly, `get_dept_employees` can be entirely removed, in favor of a better design: is the given department is not present, you print `"No such department."` and return right away in `exec_get`.

```rust
fn exec_get(cmd_tokens: &Vec<&str>, dict: &mut HashMap<String, Vec<String>>) {
  [...]
  let employees = match cmd_tokens.get(1) {
    Some(&"ALL") => get_all_employees(dict),
    Some(dept) => match dict.get(dept) {
      Some(x) => x,
      None => {
        println!("No such department.");
        return;
      }
    },
    None => println!("Invalid command."),
  }
  [...]
}
```

There are further improvements possible with this function:

- make it return a `Result<(), &'static str>` which contains an error message in case something went wrong;
- `cmd_tokens.get(1)` could be replaced with `cmd_tokens[1]` because we have already checked that `cmd_tokens.len() == 2`;
- we only need a regular borrow of `HashMap<String, Vec<String>>`, not a mutable one;
- taking a `&Vec<_>` as an argument can be replaced with `&[_]`.

```rust
fn exec_get(cmd_tokens: &[&str], dict: &HashMap<String, Vec<String>>) -> Result<(), &'static str> {
  if cmd_tokens.len() == 2 {
    let mut employees = match cmd_tokens[1] {
      "ALL" => get_all_employees(dict),
      dept => dict
        .get(dept)
        .ok_or("No such department.")?
        .to_vec(),
    };
    employees.sort();
    for employee in employees {
      println!("{}", employee);
    }
    Ok(())
  } else {
    Err("Invalid command.")
  }
}
```

But then we realize the `match` statement is really just an `if` statement

```rust
fn exec_get(cmd_tokens: &[&str], dict: &HashMap<String, Vec<String>>) -> Result<(), &'static str> {
  [...]
    let mut employees = if cmd_tokens[1] == "ALL" {
      get_all_employees(dict)
    } else {
      dict
        .get(cmd_tokens[1])
        .ok_or("No such department.")?
        .to_vec()
    };
  [...]
}
```

The same is applied to `exec_add`:

```rust
fn exec_add(cmd_tokens: &[&str], dict: &mut HashMap<String, Vec<String>>) -> Result<(), &'static str> {
  if cmd_tokens.len() == 4 {
    dict
      .entry(cmd_tokens[3].to_string())
      .or_default() // Because `Vec::default()` is like `Vec::new()`
      .push(cmd_token[1].to_string());
    println!("'{}' added to the department '{}'", cmd_tokens[1], cmd_tokens[3]);
    Ok(())
  } else {
    Err("Invalid command.")
  }
}
```

Finally let's adapt `main` to these changes

```rust
fn main () {
  let mut dict = HashMap::new(); // No need for type annotations here
  let mut command = String::new(); // Allocate only once this buffer
  loop {
    print!("Enter database command: ");
    io::stdin()
      .read_line(&mut command)
      .expect("Failed to read from stdin");
    let tokens = command
      .trim()
      .split_whitespace()
      .collect::<Vec<_>>();
    if let Some(&action) = tokens.get(0) { // Dereference `action` here so you don't have to write `&"ADD"`
      if let Err(msg) = match action {
        "ADD" => exec_add(&tokens, &mut dict),
        "GET" => exec_get(&tokens, &dict),
        "EXIT" => break,
        _ => Err("Invalid command."),
      } {
        println!("Error: {}", msg);
      }
    };
    command.clear(); // Clear buffer (less expensive than re-allocate).
  }
  println!("Bye.");
}
```

The full code is [available at the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7dadc8424ea8d96d38862eb4a64b0155).